# How to print the number of all commented list for every project in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have the list of topic(post). I want to print the number of total commented on every topic id. below what I have tried

```
function Component() {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(ApiUrlConstant.getApiFullUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => setComments(json))
      .catch(() => setComments([]));
  }, []);
  //
  return <div>Comments: {comments.length}</div>;
}
```

below is the original link https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments

Comment: Your code looks fine. What's the issue?

Comment: Why does the title say "axios" when axios is not used

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani I am getting error const [comments, setComments] = useState([]); --- Expected an identifier and instead saw 'const

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani In this How can we know that the showing number for which projet id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

```
function Component() {
```

here you have used the function name as `Component`, which is a reserved keyword in React. So change it to some other name like:

```
function MyComponent() {
```

and try to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

*An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You should write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately*

You should use async function inside instead:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
           const response = await fetch(ApiUrlConstant.getApiFullUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"))
           setComments(response)
        }
        fetchData();
      }, []);
```